# How to set the PATH in .profile or .bash_profile in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, path

I have a script which uses jmeter. Now, instead of giving the path in the script like `sh /home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t fileName.jmx` in the script I just want to give `sh jmeter.sh -n -t fileName.jmx` in the script. So, I want to set up the PATH of the `jmeter` in `ubuntu`. I didn't understand how to do it. Can some one help.

Path to my jmeter is: `/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the directory `/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin` to your path:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin
```

Then you can use it directly:

```
jmeter.sh -n -t fileName.jmx
```

To make it permanent, add the new `PATH` declaration to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @user6348718 Did you run it as `jmeter.sh -n -t fileName.jmx`, note there is no `sh` in front..

Comment: Yes it worked. I didn't notice about removing the sh at the starting of the command. If I want to setup the PATH for this `/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext`, can I add another line `export PATH="$PATH":/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext` to the `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @user6348718 Yes you can but note that if you have too many such paths you should consider using symlinks to one directory and put only that directory in the `PATH`

Comment: I have added one more statement like this `export PATH="$PATH":/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext` to the `~/.bashrc` and tried to run the command `java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png BytesThroughputOverTime.png --input-jtl log.jtl --plugin-type BytesThroughputOverTime --width 800 --height 600`.. It didn't work and threw a error message _cannot find CMDRunner.jar_

Comment: @user6348718 Thats because `CMDRunner.jar` is an argument to the command `java`. `PATH` searches command, not argument.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by not giving the path in the script? It would be a great help